# Issue setting a td id/name in DataTables 1.10.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

This relates to datatables 1.10.x.

I'm using [this](https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html) reference to create child rows, and it's easy to put HTML inside of the javascript code that's genereated, like this:

```
function format ( d ) {
    return '<div class="slider">'+ 
    '<table id="expandInput" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="margin: 0 auto;">'+                
        '<tr>'+
            '<td class="dropHeader">Cost</td>'+
            '<td class="dropInfo"><input required type="text" id="cost" name="cost" value="'+d.cost+'"></input></td>'+                
        '</tr>'+                       
    '</table>'+
   '</div>'; 
}
```

But this only affects the child child that's generated on-click.  I have no idea how to create an `id` or `name` using the standard datatables syntax for the cells that datatables itself generates.  The only example i was able to find on datatables' website relates to creating an `id` using server side

```
var table = $('#ltc-table').DataTable( {    
    "data" : json,        
    "columns" : [
      { data : 'cost' },
      { data : 'resale' }
  ],
  "columnDefs": [
  { className: "details-control", "targets": [ 0 ] }
  ]
});
```

I know I can set a class of a `td` using `columnDefs`, as demonstrated [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs), but I can't figure out how to add additional criteria, and I need to set a unique `id` and `name` for each td that's genereated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use [createdRow](http://datatables.net/reference/option/createdRow) property to define callback for whenever a TR element is created for the table's body.

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
   "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
      $('td', row).eq(1).attr('id', 'td-' + index + '-1');
   }
});
```

Code `$('td', row).eq(1)` is used to select second cell in the table row using zero-based index (`1` for second cell). Code `attr('id', 'td-' + index + '-1')` will set that cell `id` attribute to `td-0-1` for first row, `td-1-1` for second row, etc., where `index` is zero-based row index.

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e1fb0y6e/) or [Row created callback example](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_callback.html) for demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it work with 'rowData'. Some code:

```
$('#example').dataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
        'targets': [4], 'createdCell': function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
            td.id = "ID_For_TD_" + rowData.ObjId;
        }
    }],
});
```